# default value not printing in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to print the value of strVal after lblTxt in the label when the text field is empty but it not accepting the value, instead just printing the value of lblTxt. I know it works when the left hand side variable if of optional, but i am taking value from the textfield how should I make that optional? I am very new to this.

[image]

Comment: `text3` is not an optional, because you did `if let text3 = textFieldTest.test`, so the value is "safe", it can be nil.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `textFieldTest.text` is an optional `String`, or `String?`. There are several ways to use optionals:

```
var text4:String? = textFieldTest.text // assign it to another optional variable

var text5 = textFieldTest.text // the same, the compiler will infer that text5 is also an optional string

textFieldTest.text?.append(" hello") // will only call `append(_:)` on `text` if it's not nil, otherwise this will be ignored

let text6:String = textFieldTest.text ?? "It was nil!" // use the coalescing operator

let text7:String = textFieldTest.text! // force-unwrap it into a String; if it's nil, your app will crash

if let text8 = textFieldTest.text {
    // this code block will ONLY execute if textField.text was not nil
    // in that case, text8 will be of type String (non-optional)
    // so it shouldn't be treated as an optional
}
```

Your code unwraps the optional, and runs a code block *only* in case the optional was not `nil`. Then, in the same code block, you still want to test for `nil`, but again, if it were `nil`, the code block would not execute in the first place. And you even perform the test on a non-optional type which is not meaningful.

As your code does not seem to require `textFieldTest.text` to contain a value (actually, on the contrary: you want to explicitly also handle the scenario where it doesn't), you **must** avoid making your code block only execute in case `textFieldTest.text` unwraps to a `String`.

So simply **do not unwrap it**:

```
@IBaction func stringButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    labelTest.text = "\(lblTxt) \(textFieldTest.text ?? strval!)"
    labelTest.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    ...
}
```

Or you can use the unwrap logic to do the same in a more verbose way:

```
@IBaction func stringButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if let text3 = textFieldTest.text {
        labelTest.text = "\(lblTxt) \(text3)"
    } else {
        labelTest.text = "\(lblTxt) \(strval!)"
    }

    labelTest.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    ...
}
```

In any case, be aware that the block after `if let` is *conditional*.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a variable with `if let` you basically saying `Execute this code blocks when its not nil` so `text3 ?? strval!` in that line `strval` will not gonna execute because `text3` isn't nil

If `text3` is nil , code blocks in brackets won't execute.